# Можно ли переместить якорь программным способом в RectTransform?

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui

Уже все перепробовал, но ни в какую вообще...
Тем не менее в редакторе в процессе игры я могу вручную это поменять.

Мне нужно переместить якорь из левого нижнего угла в левый верхний. вот и все, для нормализации координатной плоскости.

Answer (score 0):

[RectTransform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.html)

```
RectTransform MyTransform = transform as RectTransform;
MyTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, 1); 
// 0, 0 - левый нижний
// 1, 1 - правый верхний
```

Или `.pivot`, точно не помню.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Вот так вот меняются якоря:
.anchorMin = new Vector2(0f, 1f);
.anchorMax = new Vector2(0f, 1f);

// Ну а ошибка у меня была естественно в том, что я менял якоря одного объекта, а смотрел на другой...
```